# C Concat String Int Sprintf

Tags: c, strcpy, strcat

why is the the second sprintf not working?

```c
char* jc;
    char* tn;
    char* result = malloc((256)*sizeof(char));
    int thread=99;
    int jobcounter=88;
    sprintf(jc, "%d", jobcounter);
    sprintf(tn, "%d", thread);
    strcpy(result,"file_");
    strcat(result,jc);
    strcat(result,"_");
    strcat(result, tn);
    strcat(result,".html");
    printf("%s",result);
```

Output:

> file_88_Þ*m.html

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is probably redundant, it's `==1` in C.

Comment: Because `char* tn;` has no memory allocated. It is an uninitialised pointer variable.

Comment: 256  * sizeof(char) == 256 *  1 = 256..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case

```
sprintf(jc, "%d", jobcounter);
sprintf(tn, "%d", thread);
```

causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as none of those pointers (first arguments) point to any *valid* memory.

You need to make sure that the pointer(s) you're using to access a(ny) memory location points to a valid memory. You can either

- make them point to statically/automatic allocated variable or
- use a memory allocator function like `malloc()` or family.